# Redirecting file descriptors

Tags: shell, unix

guys!

What exactly does this do?

```
exec 4<&1
```

I understand this as "make the output an input for fd 4". But if so, why the following doesn't work?

```
echo a 4>temp.log
```

I expected that this will print "a" on the screen and store it in temp.log file as well.
I know I can do the same with tee, but I don't know why it doesn't work like this.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<&` is to duplicate *input* file descriptors. `4<&1` means to create a new file descriptor, 4, which will get the same contents as fd 1 when *reading* from it.

What you need to write your `stdout` to fd 4 is `1>&4`.  However, it will not work, because the file descriptor 4 does not yet exist.  You would have to do:

```
exec 4>temp.log
exec 1>&4
```

The first line redirects all the output to fd 4 to that file; the second redirects the standard output to fd 4.  However, it will still not do what you want; "duplicating" file descriptors does not mean that the output is sent to 2 places, but that it will be sent to anothe place.  After those sentences, all the output will be sent to "temp.log", but not to the previous standard output anymore.

Comment: Juan, I saw an example of the following code:
exec 4<&1;
1>file;
1<&4;
How come 4 becomes the same like &1 so it can be reverted back?

Comment: `4<&1` makes a copy of fd-1 "location" in fd-4 so we can use it later; `1>file` changes meaning of fd-1 so that it is redirected to that file; `1<&4` makes fd-1 point back to its original location

Comment: Well, not exactly a command, but in Linux you can see the open file descriptors of a given process in `/proc/pid/fd` (for example, `ls -l /proc/$$/fd`)

Comment: And what exactly does $$ mean?

Comment: In shell, `$$` is the process ID of the shell